Why do so many aquatic plants propagate from high stem nodes rather than through the main root system?
I have recently tried my hand at aquascaping and I am watching how my plants develop in their environment. I have a mixture of plants - some small plants that will hopefully form a "carpet" (a contiguous mass of plants covering the whole substrate surface) through to stemmed plants.
What I have found really strange is that most types of plant appear to try and spread from high-up plant nodes sprouting roots rather than soil-level runners, or underground via a root system. I have some shrimp and snails in the tank causing a bit of havoc with this because they keep uprooting the small plants and I have to re-plant a few of them each morning.
This leaves me questioning the evolutionary advantage of this kind of propagation for the plant. In some cases, the stemmed plants are attempting to grow roots some 15cm or more, vertically, from a node and these roots are growing rapidly. Presumably their job is to eventually hit substrate, bury in and drag the stem down to form a new unit. However, if they put that effort into their main root system then they wouldn't be constantly uprooted and surely they could spread laterally underground to sprout a new plant?
I understand that buoyancy might make something like a strawberry plant runner more difficult to control (to remain soil-level), but the plants seem to deliberately be choosing higher-up nodes rather than ground-level.
The best explanation I can think of is that these plants are used to fast-flowing river currents that "blow" the stems over so they naturally just hit the ground, but I'm finding that hard to believe when it's happening for pretty much all of the plant species I have introduced, particularly for the tall stemmed plants. It looks like such a huge expenditure of energy to proliferate.
Is my reasoning correct here or is there some work that explains why this should be?
The carpeting plant, with vertical roots from the end-most node:

The stemmed plant (centre) and on the far left, something in between that seems to be somewhat more successful with a huge root system from the nodes:


This is just speculation, but: There's probably something to your idea about the plants being pushed over in a current (or reduced water levels) and rooting at the nodes. Similarly, the upper parts of the plant are more likely to break off and land in a new location for rooting. Different aquatic species are probably more or less resistant or resilient to being uprooted: those that are easily uprooted may be adapted to quickly root wherever they end up. (There's also the chance that your plants are seeking out some missing nutrient, but I'd consult a specialty aquaculture site for help there.)
